# Date validation with nullable and greater than condition in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-9, laravel-validation

I am stuck in validation in Laravel.

```
$validatedData = $this->validate($request, [
   "date1" => "nullable",
   'date2' => 'nullable|after:date1',
]);
```

Sometimes, both `date1` and `date2` will be `nullable`. If I select **date2** then **date1** could not be null and date 2 should be greater than date1.

TIA

Comment: Why not create a custom rule for this?

Comment: ``'date1' => 'nullable|date|required_with:date2', 'date2' => 'nullable|date|after:date1'`` will work. Earlier answer was incorrect.

Comment: @OMiShah post it as an answer with a bit of explanation so OP can close his question by choosing it.

Comment: @N69S, will add, sir :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [required_with](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-required-with) rule to validate a field X to be required based on field Y.

Usage: `required_with:field1,field2,...`. *At least 1 field is required. Where **field1** can be any input parameter with which you want to check the field with.*

**Updated code:**

```
$validatedData = $this->validate($request, [
  'date1' => 'nullable|date|required_with:date2',
  'date2' => 'nullable|date|after:date1'
]);
```

**Explanation:**

Here the input field `date1` will be required if the `date2` field has some value and is validated successfully, based on the validation rules passed to it.